# Git checkout -b with --track fails

Tags: git, msysgit

Currently while trying to create a new branch and setting up tracking at the same time I'm getting the following error. Note that `co` is aliased to `checkout`

`git co -b feature/validation --track fork/feature/validation`

**Error**

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'feature/validation'
>   at the same  time. Did you intend to checkout
>   'fork/feature/validation' which can not be resolved a s commit?

**Note**
I'm using Msysgit

Comment: Yes  fork is a remote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `-b` or `--track` options. Do not use them simultaneously, as both have similar functionality.

```
git checkout -b feature/validation fork/feature/validation
```

or

```
git checkout --track fork/feature/validation
```

will have have same output i.e. create feature/validation branch which tracks tracks remote branch feature/validation. The first approach gives you the flexibility of having a local branch which tracks remote branch with different name. Second one is a shorthand approach which sets up local and remote branch with same names. Use the one which suits your needs.